# Kohana ORM reports that record is not loaded when it is loaded

Tags: orm, load, kohana, record, kohana-3.2

I'm having a problem with the `loaded()` function of the Kohana ORM. I'm loading a record, and the record is definitely loaded since I can access its properties. However, the `loaded()` function returns `false`. Below is the code I'm using:

```
$sessionUuid = $this->request->query('session');        
$session = ORM::factory('session')->where('uuid', '=', $sessionUuid)->find();
if (!$session->loaded()) {
    echo "NOT LOADED: " . $session->user_id . "\n";
    return;
}
```

The code below would output for example:

```
NOT LOADED: 5435
```

5435 being the correct user number, which shows that the record is in fact loaded. Does anybody know what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging into Kohana source code, I found out that the `$loaded_` property was not set because my model use `uuid` instead `id` as a primary key. So I set it up in the model as `protected $_primary_key = 'uuid'` and now it's working.

This seems like a bug in Kohana though because the primary key is not relevant for this query. Also the model is indeed loaded so it seems odd that `loaded()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

How about 1st:

```
echo Debug::vars($this->request->query('session'), $session);
```